# Git add -p asks me about the same hunks over and over?

Tags: git, version-control

I'm a beginner with GIT. I've tried following tutorials on git add -p but I can't see what I'm doing wrong. I will try to illustrate my problem the best I can, but please let me know if certain parts need more clarification. I enter:

```
git add -p myfile.html
```

Then I am shown Hunk 1, and I enter "y" to stage it.
I am then shown Hunk 2. I enter "e" to edit it. In edit mode, there are "+" lines I want to delete. I place my cursor at the beginning of the line and press "dd" to delete each line. When I am done, I enter ":x". This returns me back to the interactive staging.

I am shown Hunk 1 yet again, and I enter "y" to stage it. 
Then I am shown Hunk 2 again, so I enter "e" to edit it again. 
And the process continues like this.

I'm guessing the hunk I edit isn't being staged? Any ideas would be helpful...and I'd rather stick to this git add -p method so that I can learn how to use it properly.

Comment: Do you get an error indicating you patch did not apply after editing a hunk?

Comment: No I don't get an error

Comment: For now I'll just edit the file beforehand, so that I can just answer "y" or "no" during the interactive staging. I'm not sure why editing in Vim is giving me problems.